# Double nested lmer

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, nested-data

On island biology I am currently doing a research on the difference in seed fall the between island.
For this research I collected plants on the islands and dropping 5 seeds for eacht plant.
This means that seeds are nested in plant and plant is nested in island.
My data looks as follows:

| Drop time | Seed ID | PlantID | Distance to coast(cm) | plant height(cm) | Island |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 20 | 100 | Vis |
| 8 | 2 | 1 | 100 | 20 | Bishevo |

I used the following code:
lm10 <- lmer(Drop.time~Island*Distance.to.coast*plant.height+(1+plant.height+Distance.to.coast|Seed.ID:PlantID))+((1+plant.height+Distance.to.coast.|PlantID:Island))

Unfortenatly I get the following error messages:
ixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 4 columns / coefficients
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
Error in lmer(Gemiddelde.valtijd ~ Eiland * Distance.to.the.Coast..meter. *  :
non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling
2: In Plant:Eiland :
numerical expression has 120 elements: only the first used
3: In Plant:Eiland :
numerical expression has 120 elements: only the first used

Now I am scared that the statistical analysis is not usable.
Can I ignore this error.

I already wrote some discusion on this data but I do not know how correct using this data is.

Comment: First order of business: Turn your ID variables into `factor` variables. Then fix the parentheses in your code.

Comment: Check the linked threads and https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=mixed-effect+model+matrix+is+rank+deficient and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22788314/linear-mixed-model-matrix-is-rank-deficient and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090722/lme4lmer-reports-fixed-effect-model-matrix-is-rank-deficient-do-i-need-a-fi for many suggestions how to deal with it.